# ModelForm has no model class specified Django

Tags: python, django

I am curious to see what the line `model = User` does in my forms.py so I decided to comment it out. The result was this error:

```
ModelForm has no model class specified.
```

and it is highlighted on line 45 of `views.py`

```
args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()
```

I'm still not quite sure how the `model = User` plays a roll in my custom user registration form. (I've been following a tutorial). I was wondering if someone could briefly explain to me this whole process and why `model = User` is needed

My guess is that model is now a `User` object. Also `args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()` needs to be a model object or else the code will crash. This is as far as my assumptions go.

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect    
from django.contrib import auth                 
from django.core.context_processors import csrf 
from forms import MyRegistrationForm

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)     # create form object
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()
    print args
    return render(request, 'register.html', args)
```

my forms.py

```
from django import forms            
from django.contrib.auth.models import User   
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm



class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required = False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required = False)
    birthday = forms.DateField(required = False)



    class Meta:
        #model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'birthday')     # set up ordering

    def save(self,commit = True):   
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.birthday = self.cleaned_data['birthday']


        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm still not quite sure how the model = User plays a roll in my
>   custom user registration form.

Your form inherit from `django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm` which is a `ModelForm`.

> I was wondering if someone could briefly explain to me this whole
>   process and why model = User is needed

ModelForms are documented here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/

As a side note, if you had inherited your form's `Meta` from `UserCreationForm.Meta` you wouldn't need to specify the model once again.

> My guess is that model is now a User object.

`User` is a class.

> Also args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm() needs to be a model object
>   or else the code will crash. This is as far as my assumptions go.

Don't assume: read the doc, then read the code (remember, it's open source software).